# Refresh page for all online users

Tags: javascript, refresh, reload

When a user clicks the save button, I want all users currently in the page to be notified, or even better (or worse in a second thought) to enforce the page to refresh.

So, I tried this in my script:

```
function save_match() {
    ...
    alert("Saved slot " + slot + "! :)");
    window.location.reload();
}
```

but the refresh, of course, happens only for the user that actually pressed the button, the other users have no idea about the save the other user just made.

Enforcing the reload of the page seems a bit unlikely to happen, so what about doing something via JavaScript that would notify the other online users for the save incident?

Possible related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934471/auto-refresh-when-new-user-comes-online).

---

So, what I want is this:

```
function save_match() {
    ...
    alert("Saved slot " + slot + "! :)");
    // do something here so that all online users are updated!!
}
```

Comment: I want the notification to happen when the save occurs, so I would need something in the end of the `save_match()`. @PaulG

Comment: Javascript can't do this by itself. You need to create a continuous connection between all online users to the server.

Comment: Any example @hardcoresquirrel?

Comment: I'll explain. You can do it with AJAX. That `save_match()` will create a request with a variable `refresh = true` or something like that. On server, it will set a global variable `everyone_refresh = true` if `refresh = true` is sent from client. Than, apart from this, we have another AJAX request every 1 second that will ask the server for `everyone_refresh` variable. If it returns true, `window.location.reload()`. Quite simple. Every client will know when to refresh. Of course, there are more thing to consider, like avoid overlapings etc.

Comment: It depends on platform, but this is the doggy way, fast, simple but not so elegant. There are websockets now, to create a continuous connection between client and server.

Comment: @hardcoresquirrel can you make a nice answer with that so I can understand it please? :)

Comment: there is nothing more to say, just put it in practice, 2 ajax request and 2 lines of server-side code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68774/discussion-between-g-samaras-and-hardcoresquirrel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a [Server Push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). This technology has different working strategies like Long pooling, Heartbeat and WebSockets. Check them out.

**Edit:** It is indeed possible with any of the strategies mentioned.

For long pooling, you send a request to the server and wait indifinetly until the server 'pushes' back any updates if there are any. [Check this post](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) to see how to do it with jQuery.

Heartbeat is a different and more newtork-consuming tecnique in which you send a request every x seconds to see if there are any updates from the server and if so, you update your data. [Check this example](http://www.synkron.us/code-sample-php-jquery-heartbeat-system-for-chatroom/) of how to implement it.

You can also see an example of how to implement a WebSockets javascript application [in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) but consider the [browser support for this feature](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) before jumping on it.

Comment: So the answer is no? Improve your answer, because now it seems like a link-one only.

Comment: The answer is yes, but you have to choose the best strategy for your needs. I edited the answer to show more details about it.